# sql problem got an error using the JOIN properly

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two tables:

table 1:  id, category_name, category_num, description
table 2:  id, sel_name, sel_link, sel_category

What I went is to show the category in a list.

**Example:** car in the car list shows the data from table #2 like BMW-Ford, etc.
I have a while loop that works but the problem is that I get all data from table 2 for the first category and the rest is empty.

So I suppose I'm not using the table JOIN in a it's propper way. can anyone help me with it ?

Comment: Please post structure of tables with sample content and expected result.

Comment: How is the source data represented? Do you retrieve data from MySQL or do you have arrays? Also post your while loop please.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to **reproduce** it in the question itself.

Comment: Table #1
id
category_name
category_num
descraption

Table #2
id
sel_name
sel_link
cel_catrory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted the proper structure of your tables here is a quick sample query:

```
$que = "SELECT table1.category, table.product". "FROM table1, table2". "WHERE table1.category = table2.product";
```